# Wireless adapter disappears when put in monitor mode

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

I just downloaded and installed Kali 2018.2 to my dell laptop. As soon as I launch Linset (an Evil Twin attack tool) and permit it to put card into monitor mode, the wireless adaptor shuts down as indicated by its LED light going out and as indicated by Kali network manager reporting "no wireless card found". I'm suspecting it could be an issue with either the wireless driver or the Kernel. The wireless adaptor works fine in normal mode and connects smoothly to wireless networks. The problem only arises when Linset tries to put the adaptor in monitor mode. Under Kali 2 (Sana), I never had any problems, so I know it can't be a problem with the adaptor itself.

Comment: What do you want us to do? There's no question here yet that I can see.

Comment: I don't know how to fix this. What should I do to narrow down the cause and fix the problem? The card is detected again only after reboot.

Comment: This is not a security forum to explain how this works. You are not having a Unix problem. If you do not understand the implications of what you are doing, you would better shy way from exploits and kali.

Comment: @Rui F Ribeiro, I know quite enough. I've been a long Sana user. My question is not without precedents in this forum: Kernel and driver related questions abound. I've done my own research and tried many fixes to no avail. I used _ifconfig_, and _iwconfig_, downgraded the kernel, reinstalled the driver but nothing works. I'm not breaking any rules, so don't tell me what to do!

Comment: The question lacks vital details to be answered, and is overly a low quality question. It does not very representative that you know what you are doing. It might also be more suited to security stack exchange than here if properly written

Comment: Wireless adapter:  BCM3411. Driver used: b43. Kernel version 4.15. Btw, it's ok if you cannot answer the question.

Comment: Please add that to your question, along with a question that can be answered. (Editing your question will also queue it for review to be reopened.)

Comment: @Sara you're now using two different accounts. I'd suggest you [ask for them to be merged](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: @roaima thank you. I've just done that. I cannot edit my question because it's posted from a guest account.

Comment: Problem fixed by installing and loading Kernel version 4.0.0 alongside stock Kernel version 4.15